# How ethtool -S <interface name> is able to give stat about brodcast message received

Tags: networking, kernel, interface, kali-linux-tools, broadcasting

I need to check the number of incoming broadcast message and limit them based on specific threshold value.

I have been surfing ethtool.c file and not able to get the structure which captures the data(rx_broadcast).

It should be present in struct net_device or/and struct ethtool_ops.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to read/view UDP broadcast messages sent to the broadcast IP on a certain port?

Comment: I actually want to browse the code which gives the statistics data for ethtool -S etho cmnd. where etho is an interface and -S|--statistics option is for getting the statistics.

Comment: below is an example out put -                                                                                  
$ ethtool -S enp0s3
NIC statistics:
 tx_broadcast: 8  //Need the code which gives this data from kernel.